# Laravel strange behaviour when referencing custom classes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Alright, so the [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) is behaving strangely for me for the past few days.

I am developing a [Laravel Package](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages) and have the following directory structure:

```
vendor
-student
--myPackage
---src
----controllers
----models
----mail
----routes
----views
```

Example of one of my model file:

```
<?php

namespace Student\myPackage\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

class MyClass extends BaseModel
{
    //
}
```

I am trying to access the model file in my controller, like this `use Student\myPackage\Model\MyClass as aMyClass`. I have several models in the models directory and every model is under the same namespace, which is `Student\myPackage\Model`

The problem is I am getting the following error, when visiting the route.

> **FatalThrowableError**
>
> Class 'Student\myPackage\Model\MyClass' not found

I was having this error on only one model class, and that too when it is referenced in a controller, if I reference it in the route file, like below, then there is no problem.

```
use Student\myPackage\Model\MyClass as aMyClass

Route::get('/test', function() {
    $g = new aMyClass; ($g);
})->middleware('web');
```

I even wiping the model file out then re-coded everything, yet the problem persisted. Then in my controller I re-wrote the use statement for all the model classes that were being used and it worked. Remember I even re-wrote the use statement of the said class many times but it just didn't work. Anyways, so now it is working, but now I have the same issue with an another class, a mailable class that is.

**What could be the problem, is it about the order in which the classes are referenced or something about namespaces I am missing ?**

---

Composer.json of the package

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Student\\myPackage\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share the autoloading bit of your composer.json?

Comment: You need to give full path like: `"psr-0": {
        "Student\\MyPackage\\": "student/myPackage/src"
    }` Try this and let me know if this works!

Comment: @HirenGohel No, it did not work.

Comment: Had you defined your new Service Provider to the array of Service Providers in file `config/app.php`

Comment: @HirenGohel Yes I have. But there is no reference of the model classes in my new ServiceProvider. I don't know how to do that. Could it be the problem ?

Comment: First you need to define it like: `Student\myPackage\YourServiceProvider::class,` in `config/app.php` file in `provider` array

Comment: @HirenGohel That I have done. What I have not done is register models in my ServiceProvider, I don't even know if it is required or not and how to do it.

Comment: How does Laravel know about your routes.php file and your Controller? This is where your Service Provider comes in for register!! You need to register in serviceProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to pluralize your models namespace.

Try with this `use` statement :

```
use Student\myPackage\Models\MyClass as aMyClass;
```

Your models are in `src/models`, composer will namespace your models as  `Student\myPackage\Models`

Answer (score 0):

Your namespacing is not correct

```
Student\myPackage\Model\MyClass
```

Change it to

```
Student\myPackage\Models\MyClass
```

After you have checked this, register your service provider (aliases if any). Using aliases will help you in saving time and effort.